# not able to see all services in kylo ui

Tags: kylo

I am not able to get HDFS, Hive and Spark on Kylo UI under service section.
[image]

Does anybody has any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the [documentation](http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/ServiceMonitorPlugins.html) for the service monitor plugins and their configuration files. There are two sections, one for CDH (Cloudera), and another for HDP (Hortonworks).

**CDH**

1. Install the service monitor plugin jar at `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin` and configure its property file at `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/`.

   ```
   cp /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-cloudera-service-<version>.jar /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin
   chown kylo:kylo /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/kylo-service-monitor-cloudera-service-<version>.jar
   ```
2. Create service configuration file `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/cloudera.properties` which belongs to user Kylo runs with. Populate these properties and change the values if needed as per your configuration for Cloudera Manager. **Note the `cloudera.services.status` property which defines cluster services that Kylo will monitor.**

   ```
   clouderaRestClientConfig.username=cloudera
   clouderaRestClientConfig.password=cloudera
   clouderaRestClientConfig.serverUrl=127.0.0.1
   clouderaRestClientConfig.port=7180
   cloudera.services.status=HDFS/[DATANODE,NAMENODE,SECONDARYNAMENODE],HIVE/[HIVEMETASTORE,HIVESERVER2],YARN,SQOOP`
   ```
3. Restart Kylo services

   ```
   service kylo-services restart
   ```

**HDP**

1. Install the service monitor plugin jar at `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin` and configure its property file at `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/`.

   ```
   cp /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-<version>.jar /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin
   chown kylo:kylo /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-<version>.jar
   ```
2. Create service configuration file `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/ambari.properties` which belongs to user Kylo runs with. Populate these properties and change the values if needed as per your configuration for Ambari. **Note the `ambari.services.status` property which defines cluster services that Kylo will monitor.**

   ```
   ambariRestClientConfig.host=127.0.0.1
   ambariRestClientConfig.port=8080
   ambariRestClientConfig.username=admin
   ambariRestClientConfig.password=admin
   ambari.services.status=HDFS/[DATANODE,NAMENODE,SECONDARYNAMENODE],HIVE/[HIVEMETASTORE,HIVESERVER2],YARN,SQOOP
   ```
3. Restart Kylo services

   ```
   service kylo-services restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are service plugins that need to be installed depending on whether you're on CDH or HDP.

http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/ServiceMonitorPlugins.html

## Cloudera Manager

Install the plugin JAR file:

```
cp /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-cloudera-service-<version>.jar /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin
chown kylo:kylo /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/kylo-service-monitor-cloudera-service-<version>.jar
```

Create a `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/cloudera.properties` configuration file:

```
clouderaRestClientConfig.username=cloudera
clouderaRestClientConfig.password=cloudera
clouderaRestClientConfig.serverUrl=127.0.0.1
clouderaRestClientConfig.port=7180
cloudera.services.status=HDFS/[DATANODE,NAMENODE,SECONDARYNAMENODE],HIVE/[HIVEMETASTORE,HIVESERVER2],YARN,SQOOP
```

Then restart Kylo:

```
sudo service kylo-services restart
```

## Ambari

Install the plugin JAR file:

```
cp /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-<version>.jar /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin
chown kylo:kylo /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-<version>.jar
```

Create a `/opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/ambari.properties` configuration file:

```
ambariRestClientConfig.host=127.0.0.1
ambariRestClientConfig.port=8080
ambariRestClientConfig.username=admin
ambariRestClientConfig.password=admin
ambari.services.status=HDFS/[DATANODE,NAMENODE,SECONDARYNAMENODE],HIVE/[HIVEMETASTORE,HIVESERVER2],YARN,SQOOP
```

Then restart Kylo:

```
sudo service kylo-services restart
```

Comment: I am using apache distribution of hadoop not cloudera. How can I configure?

Comment: Kylo only has plugins for Ambari and Cloudera Manager. If you do not have either then you would need to create your own plugin to see the services in Kylo.